# How I can format a date in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I want to convert a custom date format `DD-%%%-YYYY` to a standard one: `YYYYMMDD`

Possible values of `%%%` are:

```
Jan Fev Mar Avr Mai Jun Jui Aou Sep Oct Nov Dec
```

Assuming the input is a bash variable, how do I transform it to the standard format?

Example:

```
$ fr_date='09-Aou-2018'
$ # [transformation]
# sql_date should now contain 20180809
$ echo "$sql_date"
20180809
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `date` utility.

```
fr_date='09-Aug-2018'
sql_date="$(date --date=$fr_date +%Y%m%d)"
echo $sql_date
20180809
```

Please also refer to the [date man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html) for more information.

Additionally, `date` does not support custom locales, format must be locale independent. Try to store dates as simple Unix epoch.

Answer (score 0):

## Solution 1: Rewrite the french months into english, then use date to read and format it:

### Pure bash:

```
tmp=${fr_date/Fev/Feb} tmp=${tmp/Avr/Apr} tmp=${tmp/Mai/May}
tmp=${tmp/Jui/Jul} tmp=${tmp/Aou/Aug}
sql_date=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$tmp")
```

### With sed:

```
tmp=$(sed 's/Fev/Feb;s/Avr/Apr;s/Mai/May;s/Jui/Jul;s/Aou/Aug' <<<"$fr_date")
sql_date=$(date +%Y%m%d -d "$tmp")
```

## Solution 2: Assign to each month its corresponding number:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Requires bash 4 for associative arrays
declare -A month_map=(
[Jan]=01 [Fev]=02 [Mar]=03 [Avr]=04 [Mai]=05 [Jun]=06
[Jui]=07 [Aou]=08 [Sep]=09 [Oct]=10 [Nov]=11[Dec]=12
)
IFS=- read -r day month year <<<"$fr_date"
sql_date=$year${month_map[$month]}$day
```